# Is there still a reason to make my Throwables serializable?

Tags: java, exception, serialization, jboss, software-design

Throwable implements Serializable. So all Throwables should actually be serializable. I get it. But is there really still a need to make them actually serializable? I think in many cases the answer is no.

If I'm using RMI then this makes sense. But if I implement a REST resource using jax-rs and I have an ExceptionMapper that maps my Exceptions to - let's say - "application/problem+json" then it is not really necessary to make my exceptions actually serializable.

I'm usually not making my Exceptions serializable because it means extra work and I don't see the point. Maybe if I would write a library it would make sense. Any thoughts on this?

The reason I started thinking about this is that our code analysis tool states the following if the exception is not serializable:

> Fields in a Serializable class must themselves be either Serializable
> or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or
> deserialized. For instance, under load, most J2EE application
> frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly Serializable object
> with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program
> crashes, and open the door to attackers. In general a Serializable
> class is expected to fulfil its contract and not have an unexpected
> behaviour when an instance is serialized.
>
> This rule raises an issue on non-Serializable fields, and on
> collection fields when they are not private (because they could be
> assigned non-Serializable values externally), and when they are
> assigned non-Serializable types within the class.

I cannot really think of a case where a J2EE application framework would have to flush an exception to disk.

My application runs in a JBoss AS.